# Delete old records

Tags: sqlite, datetime, date

I have a column in my sqlite table which is string and has the following format

> 2011-09-06 18:34:55.863414

You can see that it identifies date and time. I'd like to construct a query that will
delete all records that are older than certain date and time.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your date is already in the best format (largest time-period values to smallest)

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE myDateField < '2011-09-06 18:34:55.863414'
```

BTW -- dates are strings in sqllite, AFAIK (which is why the format matters -- biggest values to smallest, so it works alphabetically too).  IF you want to treat them as dates, you can use functions.  Some good examples here: http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 2):

`DELETE FROM tablename WHERE columnname < '2011-09-06 18:34:55.863414'`

See:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html